# Capitalize letter after exclamation mark

Tags: python, letter, capitalize

I have string that needs to be capitalized after "!": 
I have made a script that works to a certain extent but gives me a problem when the last letter is "!".

```
strin "hello! there!" 

strout = []

for i in range(len(strin)):     
    if strin[i-2] == '!':
        strout.append((strin[i]).capitalize())

    else:
        strout.append(strin[i])
    strout[0] = strout[0].capitalize()

newStr = "".join(strout)
```

Output is: HEllo! There!

What can I do to prevent the second letter to be capitalized. 
The reason for `[i-2]` is whenever the loop encounters a '!' in the middle of text it capitalizes the letter *i*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple solution would be to capitalize only if `i-2 >= 0`.

try this:

```py
strin = "hello! there!"

strout = []

for i in range(len(strin)):
    if i-2>=0 and strin[i-2] == '!':
        strout.append((strin[i]).capitalize())
    else:
        strout.append(strin[i])
strout[0] = strout[0].capitalize()

newStr = "".join(strout)

print(newStr)
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
string = "hello! there!"
'! '.join(map(lambda s: s.lstrip().capitalize(), string.split('!')))
```

Comment: What can I add to this if I want it to capitalize after punctuation- and question mark?

Comment: @vectorizinglife Could you provide an example (test string and expected result)?

Answer (score 2):

If `i` is zero or one, then `i-2` will map on `-2` and `-1` respectively. In Python `-1` means the last element. So it will capitalize the `E` as you noticed.

It might make more sense to start at index `2`:

```
strin = "hello! there!" 

strout = list(strin[:2])
for i in range(2, len(strin)):
    if strin[i-2] == '!':
        strout.append(strin[i].capitalize())
    else:
        strout.append(strin[i])
strout[0] = strout[0].capitalize()
result = ''.join(strout)
```

That being said, using a regular expression is probably more declarative here:

```
from re import compile as recompile

rgx = recompile(r'(?:[!]\s*|^)[a-z]')

outp = rgx.sub(lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), strin)
```

This will capitalize the first character, as well as all characters following an exclamation mark, regardless of the number of spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

I used lstrip() in case there was a space or spaces preceding the character that you want to capitalize.

```
string = 'Hello! world'

capitalize = string.split('!')[1].lstrip().capitalize()  # replace .capitalize() with .upper to cap all letters

print(capitalize)
```